# Kubernetes Python library not passing imagePullSecrets value

Tags: python, docker, authentication, kubernetes, repository

I'm trying to dynamically pull images from a private repository using python Kubernetes (K8) library. I have a docker-registry secret that my manual pod creations use successfully (including the one time creation of the program I'm posting code from) but using same syntax with the K8 library results in the secret not being passed.

Python 3.8, kubernetes==27.2.0

> Failed to pull image "Known good image": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "Known good image": failed to resolve reference "Known good image": pulling from host "Known good host" failed with status code [manifests development]: 401 Unauthorized

regcred command:

```
microk8s kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=<repo> --docker-username=<user> --docker-password=<password> --docker-email=<email> -n dev-system-servants
```

I'm using Pod type manifest with json formatting:

`container_list = []`

Some code setting up the variables

```
        container_list.append({
            'name': servant,
            'image': image,
            'imagePullPolicy': 'Always',
            'command': cli_args,
            'env': [{'name': 'NAMESPACE', 'value': SVC_NAMESPACE}],
            'volumeMounts': [{
                'name': 'dir1',
                'mountPath': 'dir1'},{
                'name': 'dir2',
                'mountPath': 'dir2'}
            ]
        })

    if container_list:
        pod_manifest = {
            'apiVersion': 'v1',
            'kind': 'Pod',
            'metadata': {
                'name': name[:63]
            }, 'spec': {
                'image_pull_secrets:': [{'name': 'regcred'}],
                'containers': container_list,
                'volumes': [{
                    'name': 'dir1',
                    'hostPath': {
                        'path': 'dir1',
                        'type': 'DirectoryOrCreate'}
                    },
                    {
                    'name': 'dir2',
                    'hostPath': {
                        'path': 'dir2',
                        'type': 'DirectoryOrCreate'}}]
            }
        }
        print(f"Pod {name} does not exist, Creating it...\nmanifest used: {pod_manifest}")
        resp = api_instance.create_namespaced_pod(body=pod_manifest, namespace=NAMESPACE, async_req=True)
        print(resp.get(timeout=30))
```

Response:

The most important field is this but included entire response just in case

`'image_pull_secrets': None,`

```
manifest used: {'apiVersion': 'v1', 'kind': 'Pod', 'metadata': {'name': '<pod>'}, 'spec': {'image_pull_secrets:': [{'name': 'regcred'}], 'containers': [{'name': '<pod>', 'image': '<known working image>', 'imagePullPolicy': 'Always', 'command': ['<command>'], 'env': [{'name': 'NAMESPACE', 'value': 'dev-system'}], 'volumeMounts': [{'name': 'dir1', 'mountPath': 'dir1'}, {'name': 'dir2', 'mountPath': 'dir2'}]}], 'volumes': [{'name': 'dir1', 'hostPath': {'path': 'dir1', 'type': 'DirectoryOrCreate'}}, {'name': 'dir2', 'hostPath': {'path': 'dir2', 'type': 'DirectoryOrCreate'}}]}}
{'api_version': 'v1',
 'kind': 'Pod',
 'metadata': {'annotations': None,
              'creation_timestamp': datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 6, 14, 35, 44, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
              'deletion_grace_period_seconds': None,
              'deletion_timestamp': None,
              'finalizers': None,
              'generate_name': None,
              'generation': None,
              'labels': None,
              'managed_fields': [{'api_version': 'v1',
                                  'fields_type': 'FieldsV1',
                                  'fields_v1': {'f:spec': {'f:containers': {'k:{"name":"pod"}': {'.': {},
                                                                                                         'f:command': {},
                                                                                                         'f:env': {'.': {},
                                                                                                                   'k:{"name":"NAMESPACE"}': {'.': {},
                                                                                                                                              'f:name': {},
                                                                                                                                              'f:value': {}}},
                                                                                                         'f:image': {},
                                                                                                         'f:imagePullPolicy': {},
                                                                                                         'f:name': {},
                                                                                                         'f:resources': {},
                                                                                                         'f:terminationMessagePath': {},
                                                                                                         'f:terminationMessagePolicy': {},
                                                                                                         'f:volumeMounts': {'.': {},
                                                                                                                            'k:{"mountPath":"dir2"}': {'.': {},
                                                                                                                                                                  'f:mountPath': {},
                                                                                                                                                                  'f:name': {}},
                                                                                                                            'k:{"mountPath":"dir1"}': {'.': {},
                                                                                                                                                                     'f:mountPath': {},
                                                                                                                                                                     'f:name': {}}}}},
                                                           'f:dnsPolicy': {},
                                                           'f:enableServiceLinks': {},
                                                           'f:restartPolicy': {},
                                                           'f:schedulerName': {},
                                                           'f:securityContext': {},
                                                           'f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds': {},
                                                           'f:volumes': {'.': {},
                                                                         'k:{"name":"<pod>"}': {'.': {},
                                                                                                       'f:hostPath': {'.': {},
                                                                                                                      'f:path': {},
                                                                                                                      'f:type': {}},
                                                                                                       'f:name': {}},
                                                                         'k:{"name":"dir1"}': {'.': {},
                                                                                                          'f:hostPath': {'.': {},
                                                                                                                         'f:path': {},
                                                                                                                         'f:type': {}},
                                                                                                          'f:name': {}}}}},
                                  'manager': 'OpenAPI-Generator',
                                  'operation': 'Update',
                                  'subresource': None,
                                  'time': datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 6, 14, 35, 44, tzinfo=tzlocal())}],
              'name': '<pod>',
              'namespace': 'dev-system-servants',
              'owner_references': None,
              'resource_version': '2873048',
              'self_link': None,
              'uid': '2fd21c60-6cd4-41ca-89c8-c718468a2d4e'},
 'spec': {'active_deadline_seconds': None,
          'affinity': None,
          'automount_service_account_token': None,
          'containers': [{'args': None,
                          'command': [<command>],
                          'env': [{'name': 'NAMESPACE',
                                   'value': 'dev-system',
                                   'value_from': None}],
                          'env_from': None,
                          'image': <known working image>,
                          'image_pull_policy': 'Always',
                          'lifecycle': None,
                          'liveness_probe': None,
                          'name': <pod>,
                          'ports': None,
                          'readiness_probe': None,
                          'resize_policy': None,
                          'resources': {'claims': None,
                                        'limits': None,
                                        'requests': None},
                          'restart_policy': None,
                          'security_context': None,
                          'startup_probe': None,
                          'stdin': None,
                          'stdin_once': None,
                          'termination_message_path': '/dev/termination-log',
                          'termination_message_policy': 'File',
                          'tty': None,
                          'volume_devices': None,
                          'volume_mounts': [{'mount_path': 'dir1',
                                             'mount_propagation': None,
                                             'name': 'pycharm-mandate',
                                             'read_only': None,
                                             'sub_path': None,
                                             'sub_path_expr': None},
                                            {'mount_path': 'dir2',
                                             'mount_propagation': None,
                                             'name': 'pycharm-cofe',
                                             'read_only': None,
                                             'sub_path': None,
                                             'sub_path_expr': None},
                                            {'mount_path': '/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount',
                                             'mount_propagation': None,
                                             'name': 'kube-api-access-v5d55',
                                             'read_only': True,
                                             'sub_path': None,
                                             'sub_path_expr': None}],
                          'working_dir': None}],
          'dns_config': None,
          'dns_policy': 'ClusterFirst',
          'enable_service_links': True,
          'ephemeral_containers': None,
          'host_aliases': None,
          'host_ipc': None,
          'host_network': None,
          'host_pid': None,
          'host_users': None,
          'hostname': None,
          'image_pull_secrets': None,
          'init_containers': None,
          'node_name': None,
          'node_selector': None,
          'os': None,
          'overhead': None,
          'preemption_policy': 'PreemptLowerPriority',
          'priority': 0,
          'priority_class_name': None,
          'readiness_gates': None,
          'resource_claims': None,
          'restart_policy': 'Always',
          'runtime_class_name': None,
          'scheduler_name': 'default-scheduler',
          'scheduling_gates': None,
          'security_context': {'fs_group': None,
                               'fs_group_change_policy': None,
                               'run_as_group': None,
                               'run_as_non_root': None,
                               'run_as_user': None,
                               'se_linux_options': None,
                               'seccomp_profile': None,
                               'supplemental_groups': None,
                               'sysctls': None,
                               'windows_options': None},
          'service_account': 'default',
          'service_account_name': 'default',
          'set_hostname_as_fqdn': None,
          'share_process_namespace': None,
          'subdomain': None,
          'termination_grace_period_seconds': 30,
          'tolerations': [{'effect': 'NoExecute',
                           'key': 'node.kubernetes.io/not-ready',
                           'operator': 'Exists',
                           'toleration_seconds': 300,
                           'value': None},
                          {'effect': 'NoExecute',
                           'key': 'node.kubernetes.io/unreachable',
                           'operator': 'Exists',
                           'toleration_seconds': 300,
                           'value': None}],
          'topology_spread_constraints': None,
          'volumes': [{'aws_elastic_block_store': None,
                       'azure_disk': None,
                       'azure_file': None,
                       'cephfs': None,
                       'cinder': None,
                       'config_map': None,
                       'csi': None,
                       'downward_api': None,
                       'empty_dir': None,
                       'ephemeral': None,
                       'fc': None,
                       'flex_volume': None,
                       'flocker': None,
                       'gce_persistent_disk': None,
                       'git_repo': None,
                       'glusterfs': None,
                       'host_path': {'path': 'dir1',
                                     'type': 'DirectoryOrCreate'},
                       'iscsi': None,
                       'name': 'dir1',
                       'nfs': None,
                       'persistent_volume_claim': None,
                       'photon_persistent_disk': None,
                       'portworx_volume': None,
                       'projected': None,
                       'quobyte': None,
                       'rbd': None,
                       'scale_io': None,
                       'secret': None,
                       'storageos': None,
                       'vsphere_volume': None},
                      {'aws_elastic_block_store': None,
                       'azure_disk': None,
                       'azure_file': None,
                       'cephfs': None,
                       'cinder': None,
                       'config_map': None,
                       'csi': None,
                       'downward_api': None,
                       'empty_dir': None,
                       'ephemeral': None,
                       'fc': None,
                       'flex_volume': None,
                       'flocker': None,
                       'gce_persistent_disk': None,
                       'git_repo': None,
                       'glusterfs': None,
                       'host_path': {'path': 'dir2',
                                     'type': 'DirectoryOrCreate'},
                       'iscsi': None,
                       'name': 'dir2',
                       'nfs': None,
                       'persistent_volume_claim': None,
                       'photon_persistent_disk': None,
                       'portworx_volume': None,
                       'projected': None,
                       'quobyte': None,
                       'rbd': None,
                       'scale_io': None,
                       'secret': None,
                       'storageos': None,
                       'vsphere_volume': None},
                      {'aws_elastic_block_store': None,
                       'azure_disk': None,
                       'azure_file': None,
                       'cephfs': None,
                       'cinder': None,
                       'config_map': None,
                       'csi': None,
                       'downward_api': None,
                       'empty_dir': None,
                       'ephemeral': None,
                       'fc': None,
                       'flex_volume': None,
                       'flocker': None,
                       'gce_persistent_disk': None,
                       'git_repo': None,
                       'glusterfs': None,
                       'host_path': None,
                       'iscsi': None,
                       'name': 'kube-api-access-v5d55',
                       'nfs': None,
                       'persistent_volume_claim': None,
                       'photon_persistent_disk': None,
                       'portworx_volume': None,
                       'projected': {'default_mode': 420,
                                     'sources': [{'config_map': None,
                                                  'downward_api': None,
                                                  'secret': None,
                                                  'service_account_token': {'audience': None,
                                                                            'expiration_seconds': 3607,
                                                                            'path': 'token'}},
                                                 {'config_map': {'items': [{'key': 'ca.crt',
                                                                            'mode': None,
                                                                            'path': 'ca.crt'}],
                                                                 'name': 'kube-root-ca.crt',
                                                                 'optional': None},
                                                  'downward_api': None,
                                                  'secret': None,
                                                  'service_account_token': None},
                                                 {'config_map': None,
                                                  'downward_api': {'items': [{'field_ref': {'api_version': 'v1',
                                                                                            'field_path': 'metadata.namespace'},
                                                                              'mode': None,
                                                                              'path': 'namespace',
                                                                              'resource_field_ref': None}]},
                                                  'secret': None,
                                                  'service_account_token': None}]},
                       'quobyte': None,
                       'rbd': None,
                       'scale_io': None,
                       'secret': None,
                       'storageos': None,
                       'vsphere_volume': None}]},
 'status': {'conditions': None,
            'container_statuses': None,
            'ephemeral_container_statuses': None,
            'host_i_ps': None,
            'host_ip': None,
            'init_container_statuses': None,
            'message': None,
            'nominated_node_name': None,
            'phase': 'Pending',
            'pod_i_ps': None,
            'pod_ip': None,
            'qos_class': 'BestEffort',
            'reason': None,
            'resize': None,
            'resource_claim_statuses': None,
            'start_time': None}}
```

The known working manual pod creation, note values I replaced 100% match but I had to sanitize:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: Known good image
    name: pod
    command: [<command>]
    env:
    - name: NAMESPACE
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.namespace
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: dir1
      name: dir1
    - mountPath: dir2
      name: dir2
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
  volumes:
  - name: dir1
    hostPath:
      # directory location on host
      path: dir1
      # this field is optional
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
  - name: dir2
    hostPath:
      # directory location on host
      path: dir2
      # this field is optional
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
```